# DataContext in WPF throws an exception

Tags: wpf, data-binding

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Name="myTxt" Text="{Binding}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>

namespace WpfApplication1
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = "fdfsfds";
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder why this code isn't working? It throws an exception. What should I do to bind textBox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `Binding` for `TextBox.Text` property - is `TwoWay`

"Two-way binding requires Path or XPath."

So, you can use `OneWay` `Binding`:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Name="myTxt" Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Definitely! To be honest I didn't know that. Is twoWay binding default for TextBox only? Or for the all controls?

Comment: I think that msdn know better :) `TwoWay` is default for `TextBox.Text` property, not for control at all. I've edit answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want `TwoWay` binding you may use this code:

```
<TextBox Name="myTxt" Text="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```